# Logging enum value

Tags: objective-c

I had to upgrade my deployment target and now I'm getting a few errors when logging enum values.

```
 NSLog(@"Warning: unexpected unit :%d", unit);
```

Produces the error:

```
Format specifies for type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSCalendarUnit' (aka 'enum NSCalendarUnit')
```

The suggested fix of using `%lu` and then `%u` produces similar errors.

Comment: Where is it suggested to use `%lu` or `%u`? The compiler's notes for the warning or somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, the compiler's notes for the error. Actually, just fixed it by casting to (int).

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Just had to cast the enum value to (int):

```
NSLog(@"Warning: unexpected unit :%d", (int)unit);
```